# Anime about a teenager with superpowers who hunts demons

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's this anime where there's this teenager. He lives alone and has superpowers, but people at school don't know; he's also a bit of a loner.

I remember at some point, maybe in the first episode, this girl that goes to his school is on a train and looks out the window to see him killing someone (pretty sure he was killing a demon), and she sees this supernatural blue light (from a power or something).

I'm also fairly certain this kid hunts demons and stuff.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know when you saw this?

Comment: [_Code Breaker_](https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/13/57251.jpg) has a high school guy with blue powers. I think there were some demons involved, but I also remember him killing humans (who might have been demons though...)

Comment: Cheers you really helped me out I was looking for ages

Comment: If you have a moment to spare, you can [accept the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to show that is the one you were looking for.

Answer (score 10):

*Code:Breaker* (2012), which I suggested as a partial match, was confirmed by the OP in the [comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191074/anime-about-a-teenager-with-superpowers-who-hunts-demons#comment521496_191074).

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/11703/Code_Breaker):

> Riding the bus one day, Sakurakouji **Sakura looks out the window to see people being burned alive with a blue fire and a boy her age who's unharmed and standing over the people.**
>
> She comes back to the site the next day and there are no corpses or evidence of any kind of murder, just a small fire. She then goes to class to find there's a new transfer student, Oogami Rei, who looks exactly like the boy she saw before and wears a black glove only on his left hand.
>
> Oogami is a Code Breaker, one who "does not exist". **He is a seemingly cold-blooded killer who follows the principle of "an eye for an eye", to "use evil against evil"**. Convinced that killing is not right, Sakurakouji sets out to stop him and penetrate his icy heart.

Below is the anime's official trailer, which begins with the scene OP described: girl looks out the bus' window and sees Oogami burning people up with his blue flames.

[image: Code:Breaker artwork, various characters including a girl and a guy with blue fire]